# impossible to remove scale from radar chart (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been trying all day to remove the scale of a radar chart in chart js. Although the chart works just fine,  nothing seems to be working to remove the scale. Unfortunately the documentation is not that helpful for that issue.
here is what the graph looks like. The scale looks the same everytime. Clearing cache from browser does not help either.
[image]
here is the code for the chart:

```
function setChart(){

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'radar',
                        data: {
                            labels: ['classA','classB','classC','classD'],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'revenue proportion per class',
                                data: [0.25, 0.3, 0.15, 0.3],
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',

                                ],
                                borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],

                                borderWidth: 5

                            },
                                {

                             label: 'proportion of item quantity per class',
                                data: [0.25, 0.3, 0.15, 0.3],
                                    backgroundColor: [

                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',


                                ],
                                    borderColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
                                    borderWidth: 5
                                }
                            ],
```

and the options:

```
options: {
                                scale: {

                                    ticks:{ 
                                           label: false,
                                            min: 0,
                                            max: 1,
                                            fixedStepSize: 4,
                                            showLabelBackdrop: false,
                                            fontSize: 0,
                                            color: "#eee"
                                    }
                                }
```

```
options: {
                                scale: {

                                    ticks:{ 
                                           display: false
                                    }
                                }
```

I am doing something stupid? Any help on that would be welcomed!

Comment: that won't help much, would be better if you posted a online demo

Comment: I can do it for sure, how would i do that?

Comment: you ve got plenty of options: stakcblitz, codepen, fiddle.js....

Comment: okok I take a look, in the meantime I add a pic of the graph

Comment: @EugenSunic sorry shame on me, I am struggling to the render the graph properly on fiddle.js, I have added, data in the fields on my example to help a bit..

Answer (score 5):

```
options: {
     scales: {
         r: {
            pointLabels: {
                display: false // Hides the labels around the radar chart
            },
            ticks: {
                display: false // Hides the labels in the middel (numbers)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [linear radial axis documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html) lists four configuration options (as of v2.9.3):

- angleLines
- gridLines
- pointLabels
- ticks

Each of these is an object that supports the `display` property. Specifying `display: false` in all four objects removes the scale.

```
options: {
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      display: false
    },
    gridLines: {
      display: false
    },
    pointLabels: {
      display: false
    },
    ticks: {
      display: false
    },
  }
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Series 1',
      data: [0.25, 0.3, 0.15, 0.3],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      angleLines: {
        display: false
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      pointLabels: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```